# How to append single quotes into both side of stringBuilder object in java

Tags: java, string, append, stringbuilder

I would like to add single quotes into an array of string. If I has 5 values.(1,2,3,4,5). I need like this '1','2','3','4','5'

I have tried some like below but I am getting error

```
public class Main()
{
        StringBuilder values=new StringBuilder();           

            values=getValues(1);

            System.out.println(values.toString());

            public StringBuilder getValues(int productid){
                    StringBuilder Variable_1=new StringBuilder();       
                    Variable_1=get(productid);                  
                    return Variable_1.deleteCharAt(Variable_1.length()-1);
                }

    public static StringBuilder get(String product)
    {
    /Some quoatoes to retrive value from db/
    while (rs.next()) {
                    number = rs.getString("org");
                    orgNames.append("'");
                    orgNames.append(number);
                    orgNames.append("'");
                    orgNames.append(",");

                }
    return orgNames;
    }
}
```

I am getting exception as follow

```
  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.deleteCharAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:766)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.deleteCharAt(StringBuilder.java:280)
        at calc.getValues(process.java:8)
```

Comment: Are those separate code blocks or one? If the latter, that shouldn't even compile. If the former, you need to format your code better so it doesn't appear that way.

Comment: recheck your posted code once.

Comment: r u not getting any compilation error?could u plz post whole code?

Comment: check `Variable_1.length()` once and make sure that it's value is not zero.

Comment: Why is there no semicolon at the end of `StringBuilder values=new StringBuilder()`?

Comment: Could you edit your question to change that then?

Comment: Is this java or javascript?  You have the keyword `function` in there but there isn't a keyword `function` in Java.  I also do not see any array.  Your question is very poorly worded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the last iteration Variable_1.length()-1 returns index out of bound because 
Variable_1.length() is zero.

Check

```
if(Variable_1.length()>0)
```

before deleteCharAt

Comment: Shall I return nothing if length is zero

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what your code does but I've written a function that'll take an array of `Strings` as input and surround each element with quotes.

```
String[] appendQuotes(String[] array)
{
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String str : array)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("'");
        sb.append(str);
        sb.append("'");
        result.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return result.toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already [StringUtils.wrap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#wrap(java.lang.String,%20char)) method in Apache Commons Lang 3 which prepends and appends char/string to other string, sample code using Java8 features would look like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StringArrayWrapTest {

    public static final String SINGLE_QUOTE_SIGN = "'";

    @Test
    public void stringArrayWrapTest() {
        //given
        String[] arrayOfStrings = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};

        //when
        String[] arrayOfStringsWithQuotes = (String[]) Stream.of(arrayOfStrings)
                .map((stringFromArray -> StringUtils.wrap(stringFromArray, SINGLE_QUOTE_SIGN)))
                .toArray(size -> new String[size]);
        //then
        Assertions.assertThat(arrayOfStringsWithQuotes)
                .containsExactly(new String[]{"'1'", "'2'", "'3'", "'4'", "'5'"});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing could be done via Spring Framework :

```
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

String wrapWithSingleQuotes(String sampleString) {
        return StringUtils.quote(sampleString);
    }
```